Applying a filter to the STFT of a signal?
Theoretical doubt I’m having right now:
Assume you have a signal x(t) and you computed the STFT of the signal, let’s call it X(f). Assume that you designed a filter and have its zero-poles-gain form or transfer function.
Can you still apply the filter to the transformed signal if you don’t have access to the time-domain samples?
If so, how to do that? Do you sample the transfer function of the filter at the central frequency of each bin of the signal? Or do you compute the STFT of the filter (with the same window size, overlap and windowing function)?
I assume that you’d need to multiply whatever you obtain from this step with X(f), right?

Dunno if you're interested, but here is a very formal and complete description of the STFT including processing of frames and overlap-adding.

Yes, at least for FIR filters this can be done with the overlap-add method.
Since multiplication in the frequency domain is equivalent to convolution in the time domain, you can multiply each STFT spectrum by the frequency response of the filter, perform an inverse FFT, and sum the output signals with some overlap.  There are some constraints and other considerations to make, but that's the general idea.
For a more formal/detailed explanation, the chapter "Overlap-Add (OLA) STFT Processing" in Julius O. Smith's online book Spectral Audio Signal Processing may be worth a read.

Multiplying each STFT spectrum by the frequency response means that I should take a representative frequency for each bin (maybe the central frequency?) and multiply the frequency value of the signal for that bin for the frequency response of the filter at the representative frequency?

Baffo, it can't be just any frequency response because you might get time aliasing.  So when you multiply the STFT spectra with the filter spectra, that's the same as convolving the windowed time-domain data with the impulse response of the filter.  The length of the result of that convolution is the sum of the lengths of the other two (the windowed time-domain data and the impulse response).  So, before the DFT (or FFT), you need to zero-pad as many zeros as the length of the FIR.  And the Overlap-Add must be long enough to include the tails of the convolution.
